# Is Snomed Integration For AWS Medical Comprehend Actually Working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, medical, snomed-ct

[According to a recent update](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/clinical-text-mining-using-the-amazon-comprehend-medical-new-snomed-ct-api/), the AWS medical comprehend service should now be returning snomed categories along with other medical terms.

I am running this in a Python 3.9 Lambda:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    clinical_note = "Patient X was diagnosed with insomnia."
    import boto3
    cm_client = boto3.client("comprehendmedical")
    response = cm_client.infer_snomedct(Text=clinical_note)
    print (response)
```

I get the following response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'ComprehendMedical' object has no attribute 'infer_snomedct'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "requestId": "560f1d3c-800a-46b6-a674-e0c3c3cc719f",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    response = cm_client.infer_snomedct(Text=clinical_note)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 643, in __getattr__\n    raise AttributeError(\n"
  ]
}
```

So either I am missing something (probably something obvious) or maybe the method is not actually available yet? Anything to set me on the right path would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the default Boto3 version being out of date on my lambda.